# Install neofetch and screenfetch on AWS amazon-linux ec2

Tags: yum, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-extras

I want to install neofetch and screenfetch but I have yum as the default package manager in amazon linux and it does not have neofetch and screenfetch repositaries in it for me to install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Neofetch:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch.git
sudo cp neofetch/neofetch /usr/bin/neofetch
rm -rf neofetch
neofetch
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below commands:

1. wget https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/archive/master.zip
2. unzip master.zip
3. cd neofetch-master
4. sudo make install